# Java parse date from string with GMT string

Tags: java, java-time

I have the following date string `Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)` where I'm trying to convert into date time using the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss O (zzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)", formatter);
```

And I got the following exception:

> Text Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST) could not be parsed at index 28

I look at the following SO question [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion) and I see that

`O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;`

So why I got the exception?

Comment: Why do you call a variable `dateTime` when the type is `LocalDate`, i.e. date-only? --- Why are you parsing a string with date, time, and zone offset as `LocalDate`, instead of `OffsetDateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern works.

```java
"E MMM d u H:m:s 'GMT'Z (z)"
```

You can replace `Z` with `x` or `X` for the same result.

You can spell it out, if you want, but it is not necessary.

```java
"EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss 'GMT'ZZZ (zzz)"
```

You should parse that input to an `OffsetDateTime`, since the input string includes a Date, a Time, *and* an Offset.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s 'GMT'Z (z)", Locale.ENGLISH);
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)", formatter);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

*Output*

```
2020-02-04T16:11:25+02:00
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons is that you are trying to parse a datetime `String` (date, time, zone and offset) to an object (`LocalDate`) that only stores year, month and day, nothing more.

Use a suitable class, say `ZonedDateTime` and adjust the parsing pattern a little:

- you can't use the localized offset `O` because in a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) it doesn't support the formatting your `String` has, which is `GMT+0200` and the formatter supports `GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;` only (mind the colon). Use a combination of an escaped `GMT` plus a regular offset symbol `x`
- you have a single `d` but a representation of days that will always have two digits, so you need to use `dd`
- you have to escape the brackets the zone abbreviation is enclosed in and I think a single `z` is sufficient for such an abbreviation

Considering all these aspects, you could parse the `String` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String parsePattern = "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'x '('z')'";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(parsePattern,
                                                                Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)", formatter);
    System.out.println(zdt);
}
```

which then outputs (using the default formatter for `ZonedDateTime`)

```
2020-02-04T16:11:25+02:00[Asia/Jerusalem]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `GMT+0200` if you use: `GMT+02` it works.
But as already mentioned in the comments it is a little confusing that you use a variable called `dateTime` on something of the type `LocalDate`.
So your result will be only the date `2020-02-04` because `LocalDate` can only save this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

2 things - ZonedDateTime & missing ':' for 0

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss O (zzz)");
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+02:00 (IST)", formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)", formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Do not use a fixed text for the timezone:

Do not use a fixed text (e.g. `'GMT'`) for the timezone as mentioned in the existing answers because that approach may fail for other locales.

### The recommended solution:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s VVZ (z)", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-02-04T14:11:25Z[Atlantic/Reykjavik]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GC0SS6)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score -2):

you wrote one d and you passed 04 you should write dd instead of d like the following

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss O (zzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse("Tue Feb 04 2020 16:11:25 GMT+0200 (IST)", formatter);

Comment: Makes no difference when parsing.

Comment: I don't think you will be happy trying to parse some `String` with offset and zone information to a `LocalDateTime`...